# What is vulnerable about this C code? (Integer...)

Tags: c, linux, exploit, secure-coding

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 3
#define ARG "cat .passwd"
integer main( integer argc, char ** argv )
{
char * names[] = {"strlen", "atoi", "printf", "puts"};
void (*reachable_functions[])( char * ) = {strlen, atoi, printf, puts};
void (*unreachable_functions[])( char * ) = {system};
integer i, index = 0;

for( i=1; i<argc; i++ )
{
    index += strlen(argv[i]);
}

if( index <= MAX )
{
    (reachable_functions[MAX-1])( "Calling ");
    (reachable_functions[MAX-1])( names[index] );
    (reachable_functions[MAX-1])( ".\n" );
    (reachable_functions[index])( ARG );
}
else
{
    (reachable_functions[MAX])( "Out of bounds !\n" );
}

return 0;
}
```

I can get a Segmentation Fault but impossible to call the unreachable function !?!
I know there is a problem with the Integer but i can't exploit it.... :(
Is there a way to call it ? Thx

Comment: Did you try to compile your program with `gcc -Wall -g` (improving it till no warnings) and to debug it with `gdb` and `valgrind` ?

Comment: I don't remember there being a type 'integer' in C.

Comment: if you do `typedef int integer;`, it might work better ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you pass enough arguments of sufficient length, the sum of the lengths can overflow (not sure whether the shell can in fact handle such arguments if the integer type is 32 bits, but should work for 16-bit integers).

Overflow of signed integers (I suppose `integer` should be `int`) is undefined behaviour, so what happens in that case depends on the compiler and platform (and possibly the phase of the moon), but the sum might wrap around to a negative number. In that case, depending on how the compiler arranged the arrays, the call

```
(reachable_functions[index])( ARG );
```

could actually call the "unreachable" function. That's more undefined behaviour, indexing an array with a negative index, but it's a possible exploit.

To prevent that exploit (as far as the undefined behaviour allows), one could cast `index` to an unsigned type in the comparison,

```
if( (unsigned int)index <= MAX )
```

in all reasonable implementations, where the width of `unsigned int` equals that of `int`, that guarantees that `index` is indeed nonnegative (again, with the caveat that after undefined behaviour has occurred, the standard guarantees nothing anymore about the programme's behaviour), since then negative numbers are converted to numbers larger than `INT_MAX`.

If one is paranoid, one could also cast in the indexing operation.